# How can i get the "userId" of google account to impact with their api?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

i can't find out my userId of gmail account to use Gmail API.
So someone can find. Can you tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> userId string  The user's email address. The special value me can be used to indicate the authenticated user.

The user id / email can be found from the current authenticated user.  When the user logs in you have access to some information about them.   You can always use `me` if you are requesting information about the current user.

**Example**

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/**me**/profile

**How to find userid / email of the current user**

With the gmail api you can use [getprofile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D) to get some basic information about the user who is currently logged in.

```
{
 "emailAddress": "xxx@gmail.com",
 "messagesTotal": 66327,
 "threadsTotal": 13902,
 "historyId": "4599500"
}
```

Using this method you can find the users actual email address if you wish to use that instead of using me.

Comment: but with that way, the api is called by using library but in the test api, they let us use the userId. but i've found it

Answer (score 0):

Your user Id is your email address, or whatever you use in the user id field when using a Google login form.

Comment: @Ronald Incorrect. When the GMail API asks for a user id, it IS the email (or the special token "me") that we are to provide.

Comment: thanks for supporting, I'm working with it